# Does ActiveMQ uses TCP as its transport layer protocol

Tags: websocket, tcp, activemq-classic, wireshark, mom

I've encounter a problem where our WebSocket connections to ActiveMQ 5.13.3 are terminated abruptly. I thought, I might use WireShark to inspect the TCP layer for clues why the connection may be corrupted, but I'm not sure the ActiveMQ uses TCP protocol as its transport layer protocol for sending the messages.

Comment: @JustinBertram, I'm using WebSocket protocol provided by ActiveMQ 5.13.3

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the kinds of clients and protocols which ActiveMQ supports use TCP as their transport layer. WebSockets specifically use TCP.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Broker supports many transport layer protocols, including TCP.

References:

If you are using ActiveMQ Classic:
https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/

If you are using ActiveMQ Artemis:
https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/

Comment: To my knowledge TCP is the _only_ transport layer used by any supported client/protocol. What clients/protocols support other transport layers?

Comment: Isn't UDP possible? https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/transport/udp/UdpTransport.html

Comment: Technically it is possible to use UDP, but I've never actually seen it done since UDP is unreliable. [The documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/udp-transport-reference) even says, "Note that by default UDP is not reliable; datagrams can be lost so you should add a reliability layer to ensure the JMS contract can be implemented on a non-reliable transport." Adding a "reliability layer" is impractical when TCP can simply be used instead.